# what is the best way to test HTML5 websites?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, html, testing, browser

I'm in the process of developing a website in html5, its pretty dynamic, meaning, The first page will ask the user for few inputs, and the next page will be dynamically designed for those inputs,

Now the question is, how to test it? any tools framework or anything would be great :)

I currently know of qunit, but not sure if that's the only/good option

Note: I'm planning to test this site in Chrome/Firefox/IE windows, Safari in mac/ipad

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at Zombie http://zombie.labnotes.org/, which is a headless browser and Vows.js http://vowsjs.org/, which is a BDD framework for node.js